# How to send information from child to parent in UINavigationBar (Unwind segue issue)?

Tags: ios

I have a Navigation Controller from VC1 to VC2. In VC2 I have a mapkit view. In VC2 user search for location. When user click on any annotation it will go back to VC1. Now I want to send back the address in annotation to VC1 as well. In other words I want to pass data from VC2 to VC1. I have seen unwind segue. As I have seen in tutorials I need to Ctrl+drag the item to exit. My problem is I don't have access to the element. This element which fires go back to VC1 is dynamic.
I appreciate if anyone can give me an example of programmatically do this or any other suggestion.

```
**EDIT**
This element is an annotation, which is dynamic. 



- (IBAction)searchLocation:(id)sender {

    // Create and initialize a search request object.
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = _nameLocation.text;
    request.region = _mapview.region;

    // Create and initialize a search object.
    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    // Start the search and display the results as annotations on the map.
    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSMutableArray *placemarks = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
            [placemarks addObject:item.placemark];
        }

        [_mapview removeAnnotations:[_mapview annotations]];
        [_mapview showAnnotations:placemarks animated:NO];
    }];
    NSString*  nameCurrLocation = _nameLocation.text;
    NSLog(@"Location is %@",nameCurrLocation);
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
            pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

        //instatiate a detail-disclosure button and set it to appear on right side of annotation
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    }
    return pinAnnotation;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:view.annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    NSLog(@"Text got clicked %@",view.annotation.title);
    //From here I want to send view.annotation.title to VC1**
}
```

Comment: "This element which fires go back to VC1 is dynamic", what does it mean ?

Comment: @Poql Item is a pin on mapkitview. After user search for a location they locate the pin on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a segue using code.

Ctrl + drag your VC1 to VC2. Give a identifier at your segue.

In code, detect when the pin is tapped then push your controller with the method  performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: of your controller and handle it overriding the method prepareForSegue:sender: `

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple approaches to this, like via delegates, notifications, or passing an instance of parent view to presented view.

Via delegate:

```
@interface VC1: UIViewController<VC2Delegate>
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *changeMe;
@end

@implementation VC1: UIViewController
-(void) showVC2 {
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    vc2.delegate = self;
    [navigationController presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(void)changeVariable:(NSString*) newValue {
    self.changeMe = newValue;
}
@end

@protocol VC2Delegate <NSObject>
-(void)changeVariable:(NSString*) newValue;
@end
@interface VC2: UIViewController
@property(strong,nonatomic) <id>VC2Delegate delegate;
@end

@implementation VC2: UIViewController
-(void) annotationClicked:(id) sender {
    [self.delegate changeVariable:@"Foo!"];
}        
@end
```

Via notification:

```
@interface VC1: UIViewController
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *changeMe;
@end

@implementation VC1: UIViewController
-(void) viewDidload {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"ChangeMe"
                                              object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(changeTheValue:)
                                             name:@"ChangeMe"
                                           object:nil];
}
-(void) changeTheValue:(id) sender
{
    NSString *newValue = [sender userInfo][@"newValue"];
    changeMe = newValue;
}

-(void) showVC2 {
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    [navigationController presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end

@interface VC2: UIViewController

@end

@implementation VC2: UIViewController
-(void) annotationClicked:(id) sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:@"ChangeMe"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:@{@"newValue":@"Foo!"}];

}        
@end
```